# Name of Mathsyntax 12 4 / result: 3

Tags: notation

I'm searching the name of a math syntax printed similar to this:

```
term:  3 4 + result:  7
term: 12 3 / result:  4
```

the operator is at the end of the term

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont konw which [tag] i should add, can someone please correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation); as the linked article notes, it is also called *postfix notation*. If the operator preceded its arguments, you'd have [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), or *prefix notation*. The ordinary style (e.g., $3+7=10$) is sometimes called *infix notation*.

Comment: Weird that it isn't called suffix notation.

Comment: @GitGud: Apparently the desire to honor Łukasiewicz took precedence.

Comment: are there some other names ?

Comment: @Tim: The only other term that I've encountered is *postfix notation*; I've added that information to my answer.